# JasperReports - textAlignment does not work

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using Maven to add JasperReports in an existing project. I know that i need jasperreports-fonts to have different fonts, but setting textAlignment still does not work.

What dependency do i need to make textAligmnent to work? I can't really just add all the dependencies listed in the docs because that would make problems for other parts of the system.

I am using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
  <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You don't need additional lib to make this work. You should post the small example. Are you using font extensions?

Comment: I got it to work, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I just used a JasperReport Studio of the same version as the jasperreport lib used on my server.